# Вывод со сканера числа, стоки. Если введены не они - Exception

Tags: java, исключения, while, scanner

С консоли человек должен сначала ввести число. Мы его проверяем. Если у нас не число, бросаем исключение и вводим снова. Если введено число, то переходим ко второй части задачи и теперь вводим текст. Суть проблемы в том, что если мы вводе в 1-й части строкового значения, 1-я часть автоматически игнорируется и сразу идет поиск по 2-й части - по тексту. Что я не понимаю?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите число для посика: ");
    int keyValueScanner;
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        try {
            keyValueScanner = scanner.nextInt();
            if (map.containsKey(keyValueScanner)) {
                System.out.println("Введенный ключ " + keyValueScanner + " существует в map");
                scanner.close();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Введенный ключ " + keyValueScanner + " не существует в map, повторите ввод: ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Введено не число, повторите ввод: ");
            scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }


    System.out.print("Введите текст для посика: ");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        try {
            String scannerValueString = scanner.nextLine();
            if (map.containsValue(scannerValueString)) {
                System.out.println("Введенный текст " + scannerValueString + " есть в map");
                scanner.close();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Введенный текст " + scannerValueString + " не найден в map, повторите ввод: ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Введен не текст, повторите ввод: ");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try catch - внутрь цикла и break для выхода

Comment: перенес внутрь - тоже. я вообще не могу понять, при вводе буквы, не бросается исключение, а сразу получаю результат работы по второму условию - поиск по тексту

Comment: А, логично :) hasNextInt() думаете в случае если там нет числа(а его там и нет, там строка) вернет true?) Используйте hasNext() - будет исключение.

Comment: да, спасибо, теперь падаю в исключение. а можно как-то из исключения теперь вернуться на строку ввода значения, для проверки очередного ввода? т.к. теперь исключение выпадает и catch логики, а если убрать ввод, то будет постоянно выходить текст в консоль о неправильном вводе

Comment: Читай первый коментарий xD эту ошибку я заметил сразу D исключение вызывает прерывание выполнения кода пока не встретит обработчик (catch), т.е. срабатывает как break в том числе может выкинуть из программы если не встретит ни единого обработчика

Comment: Спасибо, а то я завис на пол дня сегодня

Comment: @GREENCHAMBER, а зачем свои вопросы постоянно удалять?.. я сегодня один раз писал ответ - вы удалили(я его даже дописать не успел)... второй раз только оставил ответ - вы удалили вопрос... с таким подходом вам просто никто отвечать не будет... я просто впустую время с вами потратил и все